# I am setting Periodic Sync 2 hour but by default Android (OS 7.0 Moto G5 S) taking 1 day, Any reason?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-syncadapter

Below is code which I am using since 2015 but suddenly it is not working for Android 7.0 (working for all other below 7.0 OS phone except xiomi phone), I checked periodic sync "period" using below command:

```
run in power shell
adb shell dumpsys content | Select-String -pattern "package.name";
```

Below is the result in power shell which tells me app is taking 86400000 millis (24 hours) as periodic sync time.

[image]

```
 JobId: 109182, WorkIndia u0, in.workindia.workindiaandroid.app, PERIODIC, 
 reason: Periodic, period:
 **86400000, flexMillis: 3456000**
 in.workindia.workindiaandroid.app  1         true            0    0     0    
 1     0     1    00:06  SERVER SUCCESS
 in.workindia.workindiaandroid.app  : 1/100%     6s/100%
 #1  : 2017-11-23 20:50:52   SERVER    6.5s            
 WorkIndia/app.workindia.in u0
 in.workindia.workindiaandroid.app AutoSync
 ServiceInfo: SyncAdapterType {name=in.workindia.workindiaandroid.app,  
 type=app.workindia.in, userVisible=true,
 supportsUploading=false, isAlwaysSyncable=true, allowParallelSyncs=false, 
 settingsActivity=null,
 packageName=in.workindia.nileshdungarwal.workindiaandroid.debug},

 ComponentInfo{in.workindia.nileshdungarwal.workindiaandroid.debug/
 in.workindia.nileshdungarwal.sync.SyncService}, uid
 10085
```

Here is my class code:

```
public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
    public static final String TAG = SyncAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    // Interval at which to sync with the weather, in seconds.
    // 60 seconds (1 minute) * 60(1 hour) * 5 = 5 hours
    public static final int SYNC_INTERVAL = AppConstants.SYNC_INTERVAL_GLOBAL;
    public static final int SYNC_FLEXTIME = SYNC_INTERVAL / 3;

    public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {

        /*Try to Sync Also */
        RetrofitSyncAll.syncApplication();
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to have the sync adapter sync immediately
     *
     * @param context The context used to access the account service
     */
    public static void syncImmediately(Context context) {

        Log.d(TAG, "syncImmediately Called.");
        EmployeeProfile profile = ObjectGraph.getEmployeeProfile();
        if (profile != null && profile.getFullName() != null) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
            bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
            ContentResolver.requestSync(getSyncAccount(context), context.getString(R.string.content_authority), bundle);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to get the fake account to be used with SyncAdapter, or make a new one
     * if the fake account doesn't exist yet.  If we make a new account, we call the
     * onAccountCreated method so we can initialize things.
     *
     * @param context The context used to access the account service
     * @return a fake account.
     */

    public static Account getSyncAccount(Context context) {
        // Get an instance of the Android account manager
        AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);

        // Create the account type and default account
        Account newAccount = new Account(context.getString(R.string.app_name), context.getString(R.string.sync_account_type));

        String password = null;
        try {
            password = accountManager.getPassword(newAccount);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        }

        // If the password doesn't exist, the account doesn't exist
        if (null == password) {

        /*
         * Add the account and account type, no password or user data
         * If successful, return the Account object, otherwise report an error.
         */
            if (!accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, "", null)) {
                return null;
            }
            /*
             * If you don't set android:syncable="true" in
             * in your <provider> element in the manifest,
             * then call ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1)
             * here.
             */

            onAccountCreated(newAccount, context);

            if (AppConstants.DEBUG) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "getSyncAccount Account Creation ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        return newAccount;
    }

    private static void onAccountCreated(Account newAccount, Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
            ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(newAccount, context.getString(R.string.content_authority), true);

            SyncAdapter.configurePeriodicSync(context, SYNC_INTERVAL, SYNC_FLEXTIME);
        } else {
            SyncAdapter.configurePeriodicSync(context, SYNC_INTERVAL, SYNC_FLEXTIME);

            ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(newAccount, context.getString(R.string.content_authority), true);
        }

        /*
        * Finally, let's do a sync to get things started
        */
        syncImmediately(context);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to schedule the sync adapter periodic execution
     */
    private static void configurePeriodicSync(Context context, int syncInterval, int flexTime) {
        Account account = getSyncAccount(context);
        String authority = context.getString(R.string.content_authority);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // we can enable inexact timers in our periodic sync
            SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder().
                    syncPeriodic(syncInterval, flexTime).
                    setSyncAdapter(account, authority).
                    setExtras(new Bundle()).build();
            ContentResolver.requestSync(request);
        } else {
            ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account,
                    authority, new Bundle(), syncInterval);
        }
    }

    public static void initializeSyncAdapter(Context context) {
        getSyncAccount(context);
        if (AppConstants.DEBUG) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "initializeSyncAdapter Perform Sync", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```